# How to loop through dataset row and see if each row is continuous with the previous row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column. It lists a load of numbers some of which are continuous are some of which are not. I would like the code to determine whether a row is less than or equal to 10000 more than the number in the preceeding row. If this is true for five or more continuous rows then I need to keep the rows and if false then ditch them.

An example dataset is as follows but I am really stuck on the loop....

```
x
560001
110230001
121480001
152760001
8580001
66590001
66600001
66610001
66620001
66630001
66640001
66650001
66660001
66670001
66680001
66690001
```

The expected output would be

```
66590001
66600001
66610001
66620001
66630001
66640001
66650001
66660001
66670001
66680001
66690001
```

Comment: I don't think `66590001` should be here because `66590001 - 8580001 = 58010000` which is > `10000`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using `rle` and row indexing (assuming your data set called `df`)

```
indx <- c(FALSE, diff(df$x) <= 1e4)
indx2 <- rle(indx)$lengths
indx2 <- rep(indx2, indx2)
df[indx2 >= 5 & indx,, drop = FALSE]
# x
# 7  66600001
# 8  66610001
# 9  66620001
# 10 66630001
# 11 66640001
# 12 66650001
# 13 66660001
# 14 66670001
# 15 66680001
# 16 66690001
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might get you there:

```
xdiff <- c(FALSE, diff(d$x) <= 10000)
xrle <- rle(xdiff)
xrle$values <- xrle$lengths >= 5
d[inverse.rle(xrle),, drop = FALSE]
```

Result:

```
          x
7  66600001
8  66610001
9  66620001
10 66630001
11 66640001
12 66650001
13 66660001
14 66670001
15 66680001
16 66690001
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try

```
indx <- c(FALSE, df$x[-1] <=df$x[-nrow(df)]+10000)
indx2 <- cumsum(c(0, diff(indx))==1)
df[ave(indx, indx2, FUN= sum)>=5 & indx,, drop=FALSE]
#          x
#7  66600001
#8  66610001
#9  66620001
#10 66630001
#11 66640001
#12 66650001
#13 66660001
#14 66670001
#15 66680001
#16 66690001
```